# How can we split string and extract the text between round brackets

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

I need to split the string in dataframe to two columns, the first one contains the value before the round brackets and the second column contains the value inside the round brackets.
This is an example:

```
study_name = c("apple bannan (tcga, raw 2018)", "frame shift (mskk2 nature, 2000)" )
results= c("Untested", "tested")

df = data_frame(study_name,results)
```

This is how I tried to do it:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(reference = str_extract_all(study_name, "\\([^()]+\\)")) %>% 
  rename(~gsub("\\([^()]+\\)", "", study_name))
```

This is the expected dataframe:

```
reference = c("(tcga, raw 2018)", "(mskk2 nature, 2000)")
study = c("apple bannan", "frame shift")

expexted_df = data_frame(study, reference)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `separate()` and set the separator as `"\\s(?=\\()"`.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(study_name, c("study", "reference"), sep = "\\s(?=\\()")

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   study        reference            results 
#   <chr>        <chr>                <chr>   
# 1 apple bannan (tcga, raw 2018)     Untested
# 2 frame shift  (mskk2 nature, 2000) tested
```

If you want to extract the text in the parentheses, using `extract()` is a suitable choice.

```
df %>%
  extract(study_name, c("study", "reference"), regex = "(.+)\\s\\((.+)\\)")

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   study        reference          results 
#   <chr>        <chr>              <chr>   
# 1 apple bannan tcga, raw 2018     Untested
# 2 frame shift  mskk2 nature, 2000 tested
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` thus:

```
library(stringr)
df$reference <- str_extract(df$study_name, "\\(.*\\)")
df$study <- str_extract(df$study_name, ".*(?= \\(.*\\))")
```

Result:

```
df
                        study_name  results            reference        study
1    apple bannan (tcga, raw 2018) Untested     (tcga, raw 2018) apple bannan
2 frame shift (mskk2 nature, 2000)   tested (mskk2 nature, 2000)  frame shift
```

If you no longer want the `study_name` column, remove it thus:

```
df$study_name <- NULL
```